# share queue between parent and child process in c++

Tags: c++, ipc

I know there are many way to handle inter-communication between two processes, but I'm still a bit confused how to deal with it. Is it possible to share queue (from standard library) between two processes in efficient way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: Sharing an `std::queue` by two processes can be done but it is not trivial to do.

You can use shared memory to hold the queue together with some synchronization mechanism (usually a mutex). Note that not only the `std::queue` object must be constructed in the shared memory region, but also the contents of the queue, so you will have to provide your own allocator that manages the creation of memory in the shared region.

If you can, try to look at higher level libraries that might provide already packed solutions to your process communication needs. Consider [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) or search in your favorite search engine for interprocess communication.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your confusion comes from not understanding the relationship between the memory address spaces of the parent and child process. The two address spaces are effectively unrelated. Yes, immediately after the fork() the two processes contain almost identical copies of memory, but you should think of them as copies. Any change one proces makes to memory in its address space has no impact on the other process's memory.

Any "plain old data structures" (such as provided by the C++ standard library) are purely abstractions of memory, so there is no way to use them to communicate between the two processes. To send data from one process to the other, you must use one of several system calls that provide interprocess communication.

But, note that shared memory is an exception to this. You can use system calls to set up a section of share memory, and then create data structures in the share memory. You'll still need to protect these data structures with a mutex, but the mutex will have to be shared-memory aware. With Posix threads, you'd use pthread_mutexattr_init with the PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any simple ways to share structures/objects like that between two projects.  If you want to implement a queue/list/array/etc between two processes, you will need to implement some kind of communication between the processes to manage the queues and to retrieve and store entries.

For example, you could implement the queue management in one process and implement some kind of IPC (shared memory, sockets, pipes, etc.) to hand off entries from one process to the other.

There may be other methods outside of the standard C++ libraries that will do this for you.  For example, there are likely Boost libraries that already implement this.

Comment: Yes, I think Boost.Interprocess is a great tool for this.