# Queue in shared memory acting up

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, ipc, shared-memory

Shared memory is giving me a hard time and GDB isn't being much help. I've got 32KB of shared memory allocated, and I used `shmat` to cast it to a pointer to a `struct` containing A) a `bool` and B) a queue of objects containing one `std::string`, three `int`s, and one `bool`, plus assorted methods. (I don't know if this matryoshka structure is how you're supposed to do it, but it's the only way I know. Using a message queue isn't an option, and I need to use multiple processes.)

Pushing one object onto the queue works, but when I try to push a second, the program freezes. No error message, no nothing. What's causing this? I doubt it's a lack of memory, but if it is, how much do I need?

**EDIT:** In case I was unclear -- the objects in the queue are of a class with the five data members described.

**EDIT 2:** I changed the class of the queue's entries so that it doesn't use `std::string`. (Embarrassingly enough, I was able to represent the data with a primitive.) The program still freezes on the second push().

**EDIT 3:** I tried calling `front()` from the same queue immediately after the first `push()`, and *it* froze the program too. Checking the value of the `bool` *outside* the queue, however, worked fine, so it's gotta be something wrong with the queue itself.

**EDIT 4:** As an experiment, I added an `std::queue<int>` to the `struct` I was using for the shared memory. It showed the same behavior -- `push()` worked once, then `front()` made it freeze. So it's not a problem with the class I'm using for the queue items, either.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233708/share-queue-between-parent-and-child-process-in-c) question suggests I'm not likely to solve this with `std::queue`. Is that so? Should I use `boost` like it says? (In my case, I'm executing `shmget()` and `shmat()` in the parent process and trying to let two child processes communicate, so it's slightly different.)

**EDIT 5:** The other child process also freezes when it calls `front()`. A semaphore ensures this happens after the first `push()` call.

Comment: where is the memory for the `std::string` allocated? I'd bet two pennies, that is where your problem lies.

Comment: May we see the smallest, complete code that reproduces the symptoms?  We don't know how you're laying your `std::queue` on shared memory, how you use the semaphore, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Putting `std::string` objects into a shared memory segment can't *possibly* work.

It should work fine for a single process, but as soon as you try to access it from a second process, you'll get garbage: the string will contain a pointer to heap-allocated data, and that pointer is *only* valid in the process that allocated it.

I don't know why your program freezes, but it is completely *pointless* to even think about.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, your problem stems from attempting to use objects that internally require heap allocation in a structure, which should be self contained (i.e. requires no further dynamically allocated memory).

I would tweak your setup, and change the std::string to some fixed size character array, something like

```
// this structure fits nicely into a typical cache line
struct Message
{
  boost::array<char, 48> some_string;
  int a, b, c;
  bool c;
};
```

Now, when you need to post something on the queue, copy the string content into `some_string`. Of course you should size your strings appropriately (and `boost::array` probably isn't the best - ideally you want some length information too) but you get the idea...

Comment: Guess I understand how memory allocation works even less well than I thought. ^^; It does indeed look like an _impartial_ analysis suggests avoiding the _heap_ would cause me much less _misère-y_.

(How DO you estimate the amount of space an object will take up, though?)

Comment: I figured that out just a few minutes after it was too late to edit the comment. -_- I still can't get the queue to work right -- is `std::queue` fundamentally the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: @ShayGuy, yes it is, most likely underneath it's using `std::deque` which also does its own heap allocation! You need to use something specifically designed to work on a shared memory block - have a look at boost interprocess, they have container wrappers (and allocators) adapted to work in shared memory.